# Webbrowser1 Delete Element <div>

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to delete all the contents of this `div` tag "ads":

```html
<div id="ads">
    <div id="ad_overlay" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 22px; width: 944px; height: 786px;z-index:911;">
        <iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://hdcast.org/ads/ad3.php" width="635" height="329" style="display: none !important;">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="close" style="position:absolute;top:29px;left:190px;border:0;z-index:10000;" class="">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeOverlayHTML()">
            <img src="http://www.hdcast.org/images/close_button.png" height="15" width="15">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed `ad_overlay` by doing this:

```
Form1.WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("ad_overlay").OuterHtml = ""
```

But it doesn't work for `ad`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ad or ads? And what happens? Is there an error or does just nothing happen?

Comment: ads sorry I clicked auto format my post and it change it. and when i try it does the following.

Comment: 'A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HomeTest.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.'

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ad = document.getElementById("ads");
function removeOverlayHTML() {
  ad.remove();
  }
```

```html
<div id="ads">
<div id="ad_overlay" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 22px; width: 944px; height: 786px;z-index:911;"><iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://hdcast.org/ads/ad3.php" width="635" height="329" ></iframe></div>
<div id="close" style="position:absolute;top:29px;left:190px;border:0;z-index:10000;" class="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeOverlayHTML()"><img src="http://www.hdcast.org/images/close_button.png" height="15" width="15"></a></div>
</div>
```

This function allows you to remove the `<div>` that contains the other two `<div>`'s with the simple line of code `ad.remove();` and the variable `ad` set to the element.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I ran it through vb.net and got this error

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Object variable or With block variable not set.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: I will try the code in c# tomorrow maybe i converted it wrong.

Comment: @Tyrone Sorry, I don't know how you would fix that error, but I hope you figure it out!

Comment: Cheers I'll try a few more things out.